# filter datatable in vuetify using daepicker?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

i'am new to vuetify,  I am  working on using a datepicker to filter a vuetify datatable [ from:date - to:date ], i couldn't solve the part of comparing the picked date to a date inside the table and make the filtering process to the data .
                   `enter code here`

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data: vm => ({
      date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      dateFormatted: vm.formatDate(new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)),
      menu1: false,
      menu2: false,
      search:'',
       headers: [
        {
          text: 'Names',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Birth date',
          value: 'birth_date'
        },

      ],
      rows: [
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Marcelo Tosco',
          birth_date: 1538006400000,
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Carlos Campos',
          birth_date: 1537401600000,
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Luis Gonzalez',
          birth_date: 1536537600000,
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Keopx',
          birth_date: 1536364800000,
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Marco Marocchi',
          birth_date: 1535846400000,
        },
      ]
    }),

    computed: {
      computedDateFormatted () {
        return this.formatDate(this.date)
      },
    },

    watch: {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      date (val) {
        this.dateFormatted = this.formatDate(this.date)
      },
    },

    methods: {
      formatDate (date) {
        if (!date) return null

        const [year, month, day] = date.split('-')
        return `${month}/${day}/${year}`
      },
      parseDate (date) {
        if (!date) return null

        const [month, day, year] = date.split('/')
        return `${year}-${month.padStart(2, '0')}-${day.padStart(2, '0')}`
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

```
                    <v-container fluid  class="page-name">
                        <v-row>
                            <v-col cols="8">
                                <v-row class="pa-6">
                                    <!-- Filter for dessert name-->
                                    <v-text-field
                                        v-model="search"
                                        append-icon="search"
                                        label="بحث"
                                        single-line
                                        hide-details>
                                    </v-text-field>
                                </v-row>
                             </v-col>

                                <v-row>
                                <v-col cols="12" lg="6">
                                    <v-menu
                                    ref="menu1"
                                    v-model="menu1"
                                    :close-on-content-click="false"
                                    transition="scale-transition"
                                    offset-y
                                    max-width="290px"
                                    min-width="290px"
                                    >
                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                        <v-text-field
                                        v-model="dateFormatted"
                                        label="Date"
                                        hint="MM/DD/YYYY format"
                                        persistent-hint
                                        prepend-icon="event"
                                        v-bind="attrs"
                                        @blur="date = parseDate(dateFormatted)"
                                        v-on="on"
                                        ></v-text-field>
                                    </template>
                                    <v-date-picker v-model="date" no-title @input="menu1 = false"></v-date-picker>
                                    </v-menu>
                                </v-col>

                                <v-col cols="12" lg="6">
                                    <v-menu
                                    v-model="menu2"
                                    :close-on-content-click="false"
                                    transition="scale-transition"
                                    offset-y
                                    max-width="290px"
                                    min-width="290px"
                                    >
                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                        <v-text-field
                                        v-model="computedDateFormatted"
                                        label="Date (read only text field)"
                                        hint="MM/DD/YYYY format"
                                        persistent-hint
                                        prepend-icon="event"
                                        readonly
                                        v-bind="attrs"
                                        v-on="on"
                                        ></v-text-field>
                                    </template>
                                    <v-date-picke`enter code here`r v-model="date" no-title @input="menu2 = false"></v-date-picker>
                                    </v-menu>
                                </v-col>
                                </v-row>

                        </v-row>

                    </v-container>
                </template>

              </v-data-table>
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to listen to `change` event in `v-date-picker` so in this case I created a function call `filterDate` in order to listen to the change

```
<v-date-picker
    v-model="date"
    @change="filterDate"
>
```

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="rows"
>
```

```
// In data defines a variable dates
    date: undefined
```

```
// In method
filterDate() {
    if (this.date !== undefined) {
        this.rows = this.copyOfRows.filter((item) => item.birthday == this.date)
    }
}
```

In my case I stored the original data that will be in `v-data-table` in vuex, so that when we filter items, the data is still there.
You might have to find a way to compare the date.

Hope this helps (: